# Is there software to detect omission of thin lines in image when it is reduced in size (e.g. chinese characters)?

Tags: images, scaling

Is there software to detect omission of thin lines in a bitmapped image (jpg etc.) when it is reduced in size (e.g. chinese characters)?

For example if the physical dimensions of an image are reduced, at a given dpi, then some lines, particularly horizontal lines will be omitted.

Windows platform preferred, if not, Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a general solution to answer my original question.

However, there is an avenue to explore if working with SVG rasterized to bitmaps (for printing or display) to see if the bitmap faithfully reproduces all the original lines in the SVG.

I started this discussion here:
http://batik.2283329.n4.nabble.com/Rasterizer-detect-subpixel-width-lines-when-rendering-to-specified-dpi-with-1-bit-per-pixel-2-color-p-td2978398.html
("Rasterizer detect subpixel width lines when rendering to specified dpi")

However, for me, this line of exploration is not suitable, as I am not working with SVG files (instead I have to use commercial software with a proprietary format).

Answer (score 1):

Some graphics programs will distinguish between **resizing** and **resampling**. Both result in a new image with a specified smaller size but the latter uses an algorithm that produces a better clearer result. (For example, in IrfanView)

There is of course a limit to what can be achieved. For example there is obviously no way of showing five vertical strokes in less than seven pixels.

For monochrome text of any sort:

- PNG will be better than JPEG.
- Converting to vector form before resizing will give a better result than bitmap resizing.
- Using OCR and then using fonts to re-render the text at a lower size will of course give the best possible result.

Comment: +1 (thanks) for the general advice. Some of which I was aware of but some gives food for thought. However, I can't accept this as an answer as I was looking for software generally to automatically detect issues rather than (manual) methods. Please accept the +1 as my appreciation of your time and input. Thank you again.